# How to do an asof timeseries join in J/Jd

Tags: j

Is there a simple/efficient way to do an asof join in Jd? For example, given tables A and B with columns time/measurement, query for A.time,A.measurement,B.measurement where B.measurement is the last observation such that B.time <= A.time.

Comment: Have you tried some of the tutorials using jdrt '' when you have executed load 'jd' ? It has been a while since I have been through them, but they are pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Yup, this was actually my main remaining question upon completing them. Otherwise they were quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jd does not have asof join. This is something that we agree would be nice and is currently a low priority project. You might try to start a discussion on the Jsoftware database forum.